# where can i get maestro from riscos?

Tags: riscos

I was recently using RISC OS Pi, https://www.riscosopen.org/content/sales/risc-os-pi to which I enjoyed the score-writing program "maestro" where one can write in notes and then play back the music written in a variety on instruments.

I would like to find the source code to that project. And or a version of maestro which I can try to compile on linux. So far, I know the company that makes maestro is 4corn, but I cannot find the application or its source for download any place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

!Maestro is bundled with some distributions of RISC OS, some of which are free, some secondhand closed source. It wasn't written by 4corn - they are RPCemu wearing a different hat - it was written by the original Acorn, and now supported by RISC OS Ltd and RISC OS Open Ltd. I'm not sure whether it's open source or not: Just because there is a version of the OS that is now OSS, doesn't mean all the software is. It could be that there are two versions, one closed and the other open.

You can get a closed-source copy of the software here, bundled with other Apps.
http://www.riscos.com/ftp_space/370/files/apps.zip

Answer (score 2):

You can get the software [here](http://www.music-notation-software.com/download.html).

It downloads as a zip file (for Composer, at least) inside are some READMEs in different languages and a Windows executable for setup.

On the source code front, I don't think that you can get it. As said above, MuseScore is great on Linux (albeit slow on the Pi) and you get the source for that by typing `sudo apt-get source musescore`

Answer (score 1):

It's not a port of Maestro, but [MuseScore](http://musescore.org/) is in the Raspbian repository. It's a very capable scoring program.

Porting from RISC OS to Linux would be a challenge:

- They use very different multitasking models; RISC OS expects programs to multitask cooperatively, but have full control of the computer when running.
- The GUI toolkits are very different.
- A large number of RISC OS programs use chunks of ARM assembly language for speed.